# Attaching images to HTML form onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching endlessly on the internet for a way to attach an image to an html form onclick().  Is this something that's possible? I have a webpage created that displays images and I want specific images to be attached to the HTML form page when clicked so that it can be emailed to me once the form is submitted. I just need a sample code and I will take it from there. Thanks.

Comment: What problems do you face, exactly?

Comment: the way you've asked this makes it highly opinionated, please attempt it and post your code when you run into an issue.

Comment: I can show you the code for the webpage with the images and the other page with the html but I haven't yet attempted to link the two together.  I'm just wondering if in theory I can link those two pages together through the onclick function.  If not, I'll just scrap this.